# FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect is not redirecting to the specified page

Tags: facebook

Not sure whats wrong,  below code logs me out of facebook but not redirecting to test2.php, after the popup disappears, the  page just refreshes, no redirection

```
//test1.php

FB.init("xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xd_receiver.htm",{"reloadIfSessionStateChanged":true});

FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect('test2.php');
```

can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/?u=facebook.jslib.FB.Connect.logoutAndRedirect),

> If the user does not have a session,
>   this function will not redirect.

Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove ",{"reloadIfSessionStateChanged":true}" from FB.init and it will work.